# Ionic AngularJS scope data value to HTML post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, mailgun

I'm working on Ionic creator with AngularJS v1 in order to build a quote calculator.
All fields have a default value "0", if the user selects a toggle, range, etc.. the value changes and displays with the correct value, but when i'm trying to send the binded value i get the default one "0"
Here is the test URL of the project: https://creator.ionic.io/share/html/2d9b0126751e#/menu/disenoweb

The code i'm using:

```
 function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {

    $scope.seos = [
        { 'value' : 0,
        'label' : "Número palabras"
        },
        { 'value' : 200,
        'label' : "5 palabras clave"
        },
        { 'value' : 400,
        'label' : "10 palabras clave"
        },
         { 'value' : 800,
        'label' : "20 palabras clave"
        }
        ];

    $scope.accesos = [
        { 

        'value' : 0,
        'label' : "Opciones"


        },
        { 'value' : 200,
        'label' : "Con panel de usuario"

        },
        { 'value' : 50,
        'label' : "Sin panel de usuario"

        }
        ];

    $scope.data = {
        'dominio' : 0,
        'alojamiento' : 0,
        'logotipo' : 0,
        'pagespeed' : 0,
        'secciones' : 3,
        'galerias' : 0,
        'formularios' : 0,
        'blogintegrado' : 0,
        'catent' : 0,
        'categoriasblog' : 0,
        'entradasblog' : 0,
        'forointegrado' : 0,
        'seccionestotal' : 0,
        'entradasforo' : 0,
        'categoriasforo' : 0,
        'mapa' : 0,
        'soporte' : 0,
        'login' : 0,
        'descargadocumentos' : 0,
        'hstienda' : 0,
        'tiendaint' : 0,
        'cattien' : 0,
        'prodtien' : 0,
        'seo' : $scope.seos[0].value,
        'acceso' : $scope.accesos[0].value,
        'total' : 0
    };
    $scope.showdiana = function(){
             $scope.show=true;
           };

    $scope.showemail = function(){
             $scope.show=true;
           };

    $scope.reset = function () {
            $scope.data = {
                 'dominio' : 0,
        'alojamiento' : 0,
        'logotipo' : 0,
        'pagespeed' : 0,
        'secciones' : 3,
        'galerias' : 0,
        'formularios' : 0,
        'blogintegrado' : 0,
        'catent' : 0,
        'categoriasblog' : 0,
        'entradasblog' : 0,
        'forointegrado' : 0,
        'seccionestotal' : 0,
        'entradasforo' : 0,
        'categoriasforo' : 0,
        'mapa' : 0,
        'soporte' : 0,
        'login' : 0,
        'descargadocumentos' : 0,
        'hstienda' : 0,
        'tiendaint' : 0,
        'cattien' : 0,
        'prodtien' : 0,
        'seo' : $scope.seos[0].value,
        'acceso' : $scope.accesos[0].value,
        'total' : 0
            };

        };


    $scope.resetblog = function() {

            if($scope.data.entradasblog > 0) {
                  $scope.data.entradasblog = '0';}

            else if ($scope.data.categoriasblog > 0) {
                  $scope.data.categoriasblog = '0';}
         };

    $scope.resetforo = function() {

            if($scope.data.entradasforo > 0) {
                 $scope.data.entradasforo = '0';  }

            else if($scope.data.categoriasforo > 0){
                  $scope.data.categoriasforo = '0';}

        };



        var mailgunUrl = "mydomain.com";
        var mailgunApiKey = window.btoa("api:key-mykey");
        var recipient = "myemail";
        var subject = "Quote";
        var message = "Test value: " + $scope.data.dominio;

        $scope.send = function()
        {
            $http(

                { 
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + mailgunUrl + "/messages",
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "Authorization": "Basic " + mailgunApiKey
                    },
                    data: "from=" + "app@pixeldraw.eu" + "&to=" + recipient + "&subject=" + subject + "&html=" +  message
                }
            ).then(function(success) {
                console.log("SUCCESS " + JSON.stringify(success));
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("ERROR " + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        };

    }
```

I'm an AngularJS/Ionic newbie, any help would be apreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You can leave your html code?

Comment: Sure, inspect the shared url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not write all your code, but this work

```
<label class="toggle toggle-assertive">
   <input ng-model="data.dominio" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="10" ng-false-value="0">
   <div class="track">
     <div class="handle"></div>
   </div>
 </label>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.send = function(){
    var dominio = Number($scope.data.dominio);
    console.log(dominio);
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/qaYPWW)

In the case you asked me

```
<select name="seos" id="seos" ng-model="data.seos">
  <option ng-repeat="option in seos" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</option>
</select>
<button ng-click="send()">hola</button
```

Controller :

```
$scope.seos = [
    { 'value' : 0,
    'label' : "Número palabras"
    },
    { 'value' : 200,
    'label' : "5 palabras clave"
    },
    { 'value' : 400,
    'label' : "10 palabras clave"
    },
     { 'value' : 800,
    'label' : "20 palabras clave"
    }
    ];
$scope.send = function(){
  console.log($scope.data.seos)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's scope.data.domino, if i change it to scope.dominio it will show nothing cause scope.dominio does not exists.

Comment: If i set var message = "Dominio :" + Number($scope.data.dominio); i get ReferenceError: number is not defined

Comment: One more thing, how can i get scope select values, it shows "0" if i set var seo = Number($scope.seos[0].value);

Comment: should i let $scope.seos[].value ? Thanks

Comment: Edit @EugenPahomie

Comment: like var seo = Number(@scope.seos[0].value); ?

Comment: It is not necessary to do the conversion, because that field in yours specific a selector, then in the NG-REPEAT HTML element defines the label as an option selector but the tag value takes the number value, nor is it necessary to go to parameter index [0]

Comment: I don't understand, i have: $scope.seos = [
    { 'value' : 0,
    'label' : "Número palabras"
    },
    { 'value' : 200,
    'label' : "5 palabras clave"
    },
    { 'value' : 400,
    'label' : "10 palabras clave"
    },
     { 'value' : 800,
    'label' : "20 palabras clave"
    }
    ];

Comment: Then i have this: $scope.data = {
    'seo' : $scope.seos[0].value
 } On the directive i have this: ng-model="data.seo" ng-value="seo.value" ng-options="seo.value as seo.label for seo in seos"

Comment: and on the send () i have this: $scope.send = function(){  var seo = "SEO: " + Number($scope.seos.value) + "€" + "<br/>";}

Comment: sorry...is this one: var seo = "SEO: " + Number($scope.seos[0].value) + "€" + "<br/>";

Comment: You speak Spanish by any chance?

Comment: Claro que sí, la app está en español.

Comment: Perfecto, lo que te comento yo. Es que ese arreglo SEO, tiene dos valores por elemento 1 es value y otro label. Como vi en tu ionic creator es un selector. Por lo tanto para llenar ese select debes hacerlo con un NG-repeat en las opciones como lo deje en mi respuesta. Si vez el codigo HTML se cargan correctamente las opciones teniendo el value de la opcion el value del item del arreglo y como label el valor de label. Desde el controlador tu obtienes el value de la opcion que el usuario selecciono, por ende no deberias ocupar Number como conversion. Solo poner $scope.data.seo + "€"

Comment: Perdona, no lo he visto, mañana por la mañana lo probaré, ¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola, fue culpa mia, en send() tenía: var seo = "Seo: " + Number($scope.seos[0].value); y correcto es: var seo = "Seo: " + Number($scope.data.seo); ...porque en el data seo se guarda el valor del usuario 'seo' : $scope.seos[0].value, Gracias